# 'Click at' returns "System events got an error..." -Applescript

Tags: applescript

Newbie to applescript, sorry if its dumb. I have been trying to write a script to check if the  network is healthy, if not go to a url and click Login button on the webpage (actually the page has 'username' and 'password' which my browser autofills). i used the following code;

```
try
set thePing to do shell script "/sbin/ping -o -c 1 www.google.com"
on error
tell application "Google Chrome" to open location "https://mwcp-ekm-04.adlkerala.com:8001"
delay 5
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "chrome"
        click at {585, 220}
    end tell
end tell
end try
```

(I know a javascript would have been better that the 'Click at' but then i didnt know how to do that)

While running i get the following error "System Events got an error: Can’t make {585, 220} into type list." number -1700 from {585, 220} to list"

EDIT:
after some googling i managed to pull out the java code;

    `try
    set thePing to do shell script "/sbin/ping -o -c 1 www.google.com"
on error
    tell application "Safari" to open location "https://mwcp-ekm-04.adlkerala.com:8001"
    delay 3
    tell application "Safari"
        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('submit').click();" in current tab of first window
    end tell

end try`

but now this returns a result "Missing Values"

i would appreciate any help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just answered a quite similar problem with s.o. trying to "click at desktop" ([here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219088/activate-desktop-using-applescript/220536#220536)) ...

System Events' sdef file says, that *"click at" still works **when sent to a "process" object** [at] the { x, y } location at which to click, in global coordinates* (meaning: in absolute screen coordinates, *NOT* relative to an app's window).

So: you *cannot* "click at" a file visible on desktop (as a "file" there actually is: *image of group 1 of scroll area of process "Finder"*) but you still can click at any window / button.

Every "click", anywhere on your screen must have an "aim". It won't work like a mouse pointer.

Answer (score 3):

I think `click at` stopped working in 10.9. Or at least

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    set frontmost to true
    click at {20, 20}
end tell
```

works for me in 10.8 but results in an error like `error "System Events got an error: Can’t make {20, 20} into type list." number -1700 from {20, 20} to list` in 10.9.

Try to use [MouseTools](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html) or [cliclick](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/) (or JavaScript) instead.

Comment: Why do the all the Applescript rules and definitions and code in general constantly change between all the OS X variants? I certainly hope it's all for good reasons. So frustrating.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to cliclick. It is excellent and open source.